# Angular Material - preserving original checkbox selection on datasource change

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

In mat-table, when the data source is changed, and then reverted back, I want the originally checked checkboxes to be checked again.
Suppose I select checkbox number 1 and 2. Then datasource is changed. Then it is reverted to what it was earlier. In this case, I want the checkbox 1 and 2 which were selected earlier, to be automatically selected. The selection contains those records, but they do not get checked.

I have a `mat-table` with checkbox column as:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="selectColumn">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
    <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(element) : null; updateSelection();"
        [checked]="selection.isSelected(element)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();">
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

TS:

```
selection = new SelectionModel(true, AppConstants.selectedRecords);

updateSelection() {
    console.log(this.selection.selected);
}

createRecordingsTable() {
    // ... logic to update this.records
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.records);
    console.log(this.selection.selected);
}
```

Now, when the datasource is reverted to original, checkbox 1 and 2 are not checked even though there are entries for them in the selection. Also, if I click 1 and 2 again, duplicate entries will be created in selection.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you keep the selection state in the data? As in every `record` of `this.records` has an `isSelected` boolean attribute

Comment: It would help to know why and how the datasource is changed

Comment: @Mel the datasource is changed when the user wants to filter data or wants to go to another page

Comment: How do you keep track of the different datasources? Also you wouldn't usually create a new datasource when filtering data, you would use the build in datasource filter

Comment: @Mel datasource is obtained from this.records. This is how I keep track of them